# Sorting keys of same values alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary where I want to alphabetically sort the keys that have the same value assigned to them.

For example: {chai:1, apple:1, dom banana:1}

How do I sort these keys alphabetically?!

Thanks.

Comment: Consider [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) for your [lexicographic sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), once you've determined they belong to the same repeating group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> items = {'chai':1, 'apple':1, 'dom banana':1}
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in items.iteritems():
        d[v].append(k)
>>> {k:sorted(v) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
{1: ['apple', 'chai', 'dom banana']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I have a massive key range and I want to output the top 10 keys of the largest values but I have multiple keys of the same value. How do I display the sorted keys along with the other keys that are either by itself (unique value) or also sorted (shares same value as other keys).

Comment: You should  ask that in a separate question :D

Comment: When you say you want to output the top 10 keys, do you simply want the highest 10 keys or do you want the keys of the highest 10 values?

Comment: The 10 keys of the highest int values! :D and thanks your a legend!

Comment: hahah thanks, i posted a way to find the keys of the top 10 items... It seems alright, there may be a better way of doing that but since you just asked me you'll just get this way :D

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(k for k,v in D.iteritems() if v == 1)
```

Comment: This would work for the example but he may also want to sort different keys.

Comment: @jamylak, then he can add a variable or write a function.  It's an *example* and the question didn't specify format of output.