# Complex dictionary sorting

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys that are words and each word has a value that is a number. I want to output the top 10 largest values of keys, but I have multiple keys of the same value. How do I display the alphabetically sorted keys along with the other keys that are either by itself (unique value) or also sorted (shares same value as other keys)?

HERE IS MY DICTIONARY AS PROMISED!

```
{'callooh': 1, 'all': 2, 'beware': 1, 'through': 3, 'eyes': 1, 'its': 1, 'callay': 1, 
'jubjub': 1, 'to': 1, 'frumious': 1, 'wood': 1, 'tulgey': 1, 'has': 1, 'his': 2, 
'"beware': 1, 'one': 2, 'day': 1, 'mome': 2, 'uffish': 1, 'manxome': 1, 'did': 2, 
'galumphing': 1, 'whiffling': 1, '`twas': 1, 'went': 2, 'outgrabe': 2, 'slithy': 2, 
'blade': 1, 'bandersnatch!"': 1, 'jaws': 1, 'snicker-snack': 1, 'back': 1, 'dead': 1, 
'stood': 2, 'foe': 1, 'bird': 1, 'claws': 1, 'joy': 1, 'shun': 1, 'come': 1, 'by': 1, 
'boy': 1, 'raths': 2, 'thou': 1, 'of': 1, 'o': 1, 'toves': 2, 'son': 1, '"and': 1, 
'slain': 1, 'twas': 1, 'brillig': 2, 'bite': 1, 'two': 2, 'long': 1, 'head': 1, 'that': 2, 
'took': 1, 'vorpal': 2, 'arms': 1, 'catch': 1, 'with': 2, 'he': 7, 'wabe': 2, 
'tree': 1, 'flame': 1, 'were': 2, 'chortled': 1, 'beamish': 1, **'and': 13**, 
'gimble': 2, 'it': 2, 'as': 2, 'in': 6, 'sought': 1, 'my': 3, 'awhile': 1, 'mimsy': 2,
 'sword': 1, 'borogoves': 2, 'hand': 1, 'rested': 1, 'frabjous': 1, 'gyre': 2, 
'tumtum': 1, 'thought': 2, 'so': 1, 'time': 1, 'jabberwock': 3, **'the': 19**, 
'burbled': 1, 'came': 2, 'left': 1}
```

Comment: And by sorting I mean ALPHABETICALLY SORTED!

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Please give a small example dictionary and the desired output.

Comment: So you only want the top 10 values (which could have more than 10 keys), or up to 10 keys of the top values? If the latter, what if there are 11 keys for the top value? And you want the keys to be displayed alphabetically?

Comment: Please tell us exactly how your Python dictionary storage file is structured.

Comment: Ok so I have keys that are all words. Each word is assigned to a value that is numerical, an int. I want to get a descending order of the top 10 keys of the largest values and those with the same values are ALPHABETICALLY sorted.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the updated information as well as the code that you have so far, a description of why it isn't working for you and the data that you're working with.

Comment: From the results of the previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953268/sorting-keys-of-same-values-alphabetically/9953317#9953317, i think the data should look something like what i used in my example: 
{1: ['apple', 'chai', 'coffe', 'dom banana'], 2: ['pie', 'tea'], 3: ['bacon', 'pepsi'], 4: ['strawberry'], 5: ['egg'], 7: ['cake', 'ham'], 9: ['milk', 'mocha'], 10: ['pear'], 11: ['chicken', 'latte'], 13: ['coke'], 20: ['chocolate']}

The op can confirm if this is valid data..

Comment: SO SORRY FOR MAKING YOU GUYS WAIT BUT I NEED TO FIGURE OUT HOW TO OUTPUT THE DICTIONARY I'M DEALING WITH SO FAR!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import islice, chain, repeat
>>> food = {1: ['apple', 'chai', 'coffe', 'dom banana'], 2: ['pie', 'tea'], 3: ['bacon', 'pepsi'], 4: ['strawberry'], 5: ['egg'], 7: ['cake', 'ham'], 9: ['milk', 'mocha'], 10: ['pear'], 11: ['chicken', 'latte'], 13: ['coke'], 20: ['chocolate']}
>>> list(islice(chain.from_iterable(repeat(k, len(v)) 
                                    for k, v in
                                    sorted(food.iteritems(), reverse=True)), 10))
[20, 13, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 7, 7, 5]
```

Comment: Not the values, the keys! :) But the keys with same values are ordered alphabetically!!

Comment: Those are the keys... how can keys be ordered alphabetically aren't they numbers in your case?

Comment: Keys are words, values of the keys are numbers (int).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but you can try something like:

```
 # Assuming the data you're working with is something like:
 >>> d = {'apple': 10, 'banana': 10, 'pear': 5, 'peach': 35, 'plum': 17, 'tomato': 17}

 # Use - to order by values descending, key ordering will still be ascending.
 >>> sorted(d.items(), key = lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0]))
 [('peach',  35),
  ('plum',   17),
  ('tomato', 17),
  ('apple',  10),
  ('banana', 10),
  ('pear',   5)]
```